# Inject dictionary using dependency injection

Tags: c#, dictionary, dependency-injection

i created a function(dictionary) for my project:

```
private static Dictionary<string, Func<IMessageProcessor>> strategyFactories = new Dictionary<string, Func<IMessageProcessor>>()
    {
        { "T.2.12.0", new Func<IMessageProcessor>(() => new HVPVTParser()) },
        { "T.3.03.0", new Func<IMessageProcessor>(() => new PVTParser()) },
        { "Unknown", new Func<IMessageProcessor>(() => new UnknownParser()) }
    };
```

As per requirement, I want to get rid of new operator for classes (HVPVTParser, PVTParser and UnknownParser). Can I improve function through dependency injection? During research, I found an option to inject my dictionary. I am unable to understand word 'inject'. Can anyone provide code sample to achieve my goal or any guidelines to solve a problem.

Comment: A wild guess: you have no prior experience with dependency injection? 
Do you even need to use DI? Wouldn't a lazy be better suited and easier readable for the initialisation of this dictionary?

Answer (score 3):

Typically you "inject" some sort of service that implements an interface.  In your case it would be something like:

```
public interface IStrategyFactoryService
{
    public Dictionary<string, Func<IMessageProcessor>> Factories {get;}
}
```

Your class would then have a constructor parameter (if the data is required for the class to function) or a property (if the data is *helpful* but not *required*).

Then create classes that implement that interface - a real one for the "live" app and a fake one for testing.